# tata photon plus not working after upgrading OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos

i upgraded my macbook air to OS X Yosemite and my tata photon plus huawei modem model no. EC156 not working with my mac. its getting installed well but when i tries to connect, it shows connection terminated. I have tries all the possible things explained in the forum earlier but i think those were only for tata photon 3g not for tata photon plus.
Please help?

Answer (score 6):

If you try to download the drivers directly from Tata Photon + or Service Provider ( Tata) website it will not work as the drivers are not compatible with the Mac ( Yosemite).

If the manufacturer of your device is huawei, go directly to their driver site and download the drivers.

Use the following link to go to driver site

http://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/downloads/detail/index.htm?id=31322

Search for following driver for tata photon+

Mac-V200R003B015D11SP00C983(for Mac10.10)

Once you install the driver, it will create mobile partner in your launchpad. Make sure you Use mobile partner and don't use the auto connect app of tata photon+.

If you have any query you can reach me at khushindergill@icloud.com or khushindergill@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks this absolutely works, even though I did not have my profile information so I could not use the "Mobile Partner" App to connect. But after installing the mentioned drivers, I am able to connect through tata photon plus.

Comment: Thanks. Tata photon support doesn't know about this!!

Comment: Hi Khushinder, This is excellent answer and works for me. Thanks for posting this. It helps a lot of people suffering headche from tata customer care supports because they does not anything about this.

Comment: I installed this driver on Mac OS X El Captain but how can I create a profile? I needs a username/password etc

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely work out for tata photon max wifi data card. Go to Huawei support- consumer page, enter details of the dongle in the column to the right. E.g. my wingle was CE315 (you will not find photon max wifi data card in dongle group). Then download and install "The tool and guide of HiLink AutoRun(for Mac10.10)". After this your wingle  will start working.